# Ввести число с запятыми

Tags: java

В файле записаны числа, означающие население мира в какой-то год.
Например 2,557,628,654 - 2 миллиарда 555 миллионов...
Как и прочитать как целое?

```
int pop = scanner.nextInt();
```

Выдает исключение.
Регулярное выражение?

Comment: А если установить соответствующие настройки локали - ThousandsSeparator или как там оно в этой вашей джаве называется?

Comment: А если ввести как строку и затем эту строку преобразовать в число?

Comment: В int столько не влезает

Answer (score 2):

Считайте как строку и преобразуйте ее в число.

В файле **num.txt**

```
2,557,628,654
```

Пример:

```
File file = new File("num.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.next();
    long num = Long.parseLong(line.replace(",", ""));
    System.out.println(line + " -> " + num);
    // 2,557,628,654 -> 2557628654
}
```

---

**UDP.**

По подсказке **HasmikGaryaka**, можно через [Scanner.useLocale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useLocale(java.util.Locale)) указать локаль, что определит разделитель между группами цифр целого числа. В `Locale.ENGLISH` это будет символ запятой (`,`). Подробнее про локализованные строки: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#localized-numbers, а про разделитель групп можно посмотреть в ссылке *LocalGroupSeparator*

Пример:

```
    scanner.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    long num = scanner.nextLong();
    System.out.println(num);
    // 2557628654
```

Comment: scanner.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH); позволяет считать сразу число.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, вы правы, спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

Возложить работу на сканер.

```
scanner.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
String str = scanner.nextLine();
int year = scanner.nextInt();
long pop = scanner.nextLong();
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых: диапазон значений `int` в `java` - от `-2 147 483 648` до `2 147 483 647`.
Во-вторых: вам нужно сначала прочитать строчку, убрать из нее все `,` и только потом переводить в `long`.